# org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkBook.write produces different results when writing to a file verse byteArray

Tags: java, apache-poi

In a java app I am creating a workbook and then want to send the workbook via smtp.  Writing the File to disk and then sending the email works just fine.  But I would like to send the email without writing the file to disk first.  So I issue the .write to a ByteArrayOutputStream.  When the mail arrives the file is corrupt.  So I tried writing the ByteArrayOutputStream to a file to compare the output.  They are different by about 324 bytes.  Any help would be great.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Object  MSWorkbook = IDataUtil.get( pipelineCursor, "MSWorkbook" );
    Workbook wb = (Workbook) MSWorkbook;
    FileOutputStream fileOut;
    
    try {
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/brad.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        wb.write(bos);
        bos.close();
    } catch( Exception e) {
        
    }
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    try{
       OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/brad1.xlsx"));
       os.write(bytes);
       os.close();
    } catch (Exception e){}
```

Comment: You write first from the workbook (`wb`) to the ByteArrayOutputStream and then from the ByteArrayOutputStream to the file. What is different? Can you include code to show the difference?

Comment: @cyberbrain -  The output produces 2 different size files.  The.write which writes to a file descriptor creates a correct file.  When I use the ByteArray it produces an incorrect/corrupt file.  I would think It should produce the same file.  I can provide file samples on request.  Not sure how to upload them here.

Comment: In your example, no output is done directly from a `Workbook` instance to a file. This is confusing me a bit. Do you compare it to another file that is written directly from the `wb` instance but not contained in the code? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: here is the full code set

Comment: Is it possible that the first `wb.write(fileOut);` has a side effect on the second `wb.write(bos);` (like storing some history of saves e.g.) ? Can you try to reverse the writes (just for testing) so that `ByteOutputStream` variant is written first, and then the file? And see if the lengths differences go into the "opposite direction" then?
(I suspect this because I've seen the behaviour of Office software that after just printing a freshly opened document and closing again, it asks me if I want to save changes...)

Comment: I have tried that and it still produces the same result.  It appears as though the byte array has more data in it.  Like header info or something.

Comment: it really has to be something from POI I think. Did you try to unzip both xlsx files and compare the resulting file structures with a tool like [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/) ?